How can we scale an ellipse (varying the axes, rotation and translation) keeping the same line width?
A ellipse can be expressed with $x,y$ fulfilling:
$$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$
with
\begin{align*}
  A =   a^2 \sin^2\theta + b^2 \cos^2\theta \\
  B =  2\left(b^2 - a^2\right) \sin\theta \cos\theta \\
  C =   a^2 \cos^2\theta + b^2 \sin^2\theta \\
  D = -2A x_\circ   -  B y_\circ \\
  E = - B x_\circ   - 2C y_\circ \\
  F =   A x_\circ^2 +  B x_\circ y_\circ + C y_\circ^2 - a^2 b^2 
\end{align*}
with $a$ being the major axis, $b$ the minor axis, $\theta$ the rotation and $x_\circ y_\circ$ the center point. (equations from wiki)
Upon drawing such a ellipse inside a plot  with $x \in [x_{min},x_{max}] $ and $y \in [y_{mim}, y_{max}]$ we can make the line thicker by allowing more results than $0$ but instead values smaller than width $w$.
To be on both sides we take the absolute value:
$$|Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F | \le w$$
If we take $w$ as a constant the absolute width in relation to the total area $[x_{min},x_{max}] \times [y_{mim}, y_{max}]$ can change with the change of the parameters $a,b,\theta,A,B,C,D,E,F$.
The goal is to have a constant width $w_\star$ around the line. Therefore we need to scale $w$ by a function:
$$w = f(w_\star, a,b,\theta, x_\circ, y_\circ)$$
Now my question is how this function would look like to maintain the absolute width $w_{\star}$ in relation to the constant plotting window $[x_{min},x_{max}] \times [y_{mim}, y_{max}]$


Trials:
if we compute the equation at $x_\circ$ $y_\circ$ we get
$$Ax_{\circ}^2 + Bx_\circ y_\circ + Cy_\circ^2 + Dx_\circ + Ey_\circ + F  = -(a^2 \cdot b^2)$$
Now if we alter $a,b$ by half the target absolute line width $\frac{w_{\star}}{2}$ we get
$$-((a - \frac{w_{\star}}{2} )^2 \cdot (b- \frac{w_{\star}}{2} )^2)$$
We could now set the scaled line width $w$ to the difference of those both
$$ w = (a^2 \cdot b^2) - ((a - \frac{w_{\star}}{2} )^2 \cdot (b- \frac{w_{\star}}{2} )^2) $$
Doing this works already much better than a constant $w$ but if we look closely there is still some difference at scaling.
E.g. example ellipse (green), scaled version (blue), 3rd both overlapping

How can we scale $w$ better so that the full line width overlaps?

To be complete: the final picture should have some sort of gradient like here 


How exactly do you scale the ellipse? Do you just scale the coordinates $ (x,y) \to (ax,ay)$ ? Also the width $w^*$ varies around the perimeter of the ellipse, what do you mean by matching exactly?

@DinosaurEgg $x \in [X_{min}, X_{max}], y \in [Y_{min}, Y_{max}]$ remain as they are. With scaling I mean the changing the axis $a,b$, with rotation changing $\theta$ and with translation changing $x_\circ, y_\circ$. Changing those variables will change $A,B,C,D,E,F$ as well.  We draw every $[x,y]$ where this equation $|A x_\circ^2 +B ...+F | \le w$ holds. $w_\star$ is a constant width e.g. 10 or 1% of the constant $X_{max}-X_{min}$.

To get a constant width $w_\star$ with every $a,b,\theta, x_\circ, y_\circ$ we need to somehow scale $w$ which is a function of those parameters $f(w_\star, a,b,\theta, x_\circ, y_\circ)$. My question is how this function would look like. like in the picture The blue ellipse has much bigger $a,b$. As the 3rd picture shows with my current approach the line width got smaller with increasing $a,b$. The goal is to stay the same width as the small green ellipse.

Already commented constant normal width $ w_\star $ is  not possible between two (non-circular) ellipses

@UncleBob: Please feel free to roll  back edited title if found not suitable.

Comments:
For a start consider an ellipse centered at the origin. Check the sign of discriminant to adjust constants so you don't get to a hyperbola, pair of straight lines etc.
$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2}- \frac{xy}{c^2}=1 \tag 1 $$
Differentiate to find $(0,\infty)$  slope tangent points in order to find connecting tangent point intersection lines:
$$  \frac{y}{x}=   \frac{2c^2}{a^2},~  \frac{y}{x}=   \frac{b^2}{2 c^2};~\tag 2 $$
These transverse lines (2)  pass through the origin and the pair of tangential points as shown.
We solve quadratic equations (1)+(2) plug-ins  and find difference of roots and so the (red) bounding box dimensions  $\left( [x_{min}-x_{max}]  \times y  [y_{mim}- y_{max}] \right).$

Hope you can fill in further to build required details on this template to include translations of the ellipse, line thickness and so on.

thanks for response but I'm sorry I have not found yet any way to calculate the invariant thickness parameter. How to continue from there?

Not clear what you want. You want to find  coordinates of a constant thickness  elliptic ring with profile  drawn ? A given thickness  can be same everywhere including at the 4 tangent points indicated. The outer curve is not an ellipse. Its ode can be given, a continuous "parallel" Bertrand curve can be numerically plotted.

Not the whole ellipse was meant, only the thickness of the blue line itself. In other words I want to highlight the area in between the two ellipses which have a $a,b$ smaller/bigger by $\frac{w_\star}{2}$. Given one point $[x,y]$ I want to know if this point is inside this area and if yes how distant is it from the middle elliptic curve with axis $a,b$, normalized in that way that the max distance is $1$ at the bordered lines with $a,b \pm \frac{w_\star}{2}$ and $0$ at the middle ellipse with axis $a,b$.
